# Singular points on parallel surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Let ${\bf r}(u,v)$ be a parameterization for the surface $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we denote by ${\bf N}$ the unit normal vector field of $M$, we can define a parallel surface $M_{d}$ in the following way: \begin{equation} {\bf r}_{d}(u,v) = {\bf r}(u,v) + d{\bf N}(u,v) \end{equation} where $d \neq 0$ is a fixed real number.

Now, I'm trying to show that the singular points of the parameterization ${\bf r}_{d}$ correspond to those points of $M$ at which $1/d$ is a principal curvature. My current approach is rather ugly, and involves computing eigenvalues of the shape operator of ${\bf r}_{d}(u,v)$. Is there a more computationally simple way to do this?

Comment: You want to compute the derivative of $\mathbf r_d$ itself.

Comment: I did that, if by derivative you mean partial derivatives. I'm trying to show that their cross product is equal to zero if and only if $1/d$ is a principal curvature of ${\bf r}(u,v)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me write $\mathbf x(u,v) = \mathbf r_d(u,v)$. Let's assume that $u$- and $v$-curves are (near the point in question) lines of curvature with principal curvatures $k_1$ and $k_2$, respectively. Then we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbf x_u &= \mathbf r_u + d\mathbf N_u = \mathbf r_u + d(-k_1\mathbf r_u) \\
\mathbf x_v &= \mathbf r_v + d\mathbf N_v = \mathbf r_v + d(-k_2\mathbf r_v)\,.
\end{align*}
So, we see that if $d=1/k_j$ for either $j=1$ or $j=2$, then one of the partial derivatives of $\mathbf x$ vanishes and the parametrization is not regular at such a point.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand, but why can assume that the $u$ and $v$ curves are lines of curvature with principal directions? Do you basically just reparametrize the surface?

Comment: @AshwinIyengar: You can always reparametrize this way *away* from umbilic points. The basic differential equations theorem is that if you have linearly independent vector fields $X$ and $Y$, *locally* there are coordinates $(u,v)$ so that the $u$-curves are tangent to $X$ and the $v$-curves are tangent to $Y$.